# Can I keep the original value of a LiveData in a switchMap transformation function?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using a ViewModel with LiveData. The code below is part of my ViewModel. It's using the `switchMap` transformation to get a list of items every time the `searchQuery` changes.

Every time `searchQuery` changes, the items are properly retrieved from the repository, but before the repository has returned a response, the `items` livedata will get a `null` update first, and when the repository returns a response, it updates to the correct value. Is there a way I can skip this `null` update and keep the original value of `items` until the repository actually returns a result?

```
val searchQuery = MutableLiveData<String>()
val items: LiveData<List<String>> = Transformations.switchMap(searchQuery) { query ->
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    launch {
        val result = itemRepository.get(query)
        liveData.postValue(result)
    }
    return liveData
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy actually, you just need to ditch `Transformations.switchMap {` and use your own custom `MediatorLiveData`. Look:

```
val searchQuery = MutableLiveData<String>()
val items: LiveData<List<String>> = MediatorLiveData().also { mediator ->
    mediator.addSource(searchQuery) { query ->
        launch {
            val result = itemRepository.get(query)
            mediator.postValue(result)
        }
    }
}
```

And it should *just work*.

Answer (score -2):

My recommendation would be not use the LiveData as something to react to inside the ViewModel, but instead use something like **[BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)** to hold the latest query and be observed.

You can do something like this:

```
val searchQuery = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()
val items: LiveData<List<String>>

searchQuery
    .switchMap { itemRepository.get(query) }
    .subscribe( items.postValue(it) )
```

This way, you can

- React to changes in query.
- Filter on queries that are smaller then X (with .filter(...))
- SwitchMap if another Query comes in before the first is done.
- And post to the LiveData when you have data.